# replace 64 different OLD strings with 64 different new strings

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file that has content in the following format:

```
wwid 525a9370dcb2348b03884049000190l
```

The 2nd field is different on each line I need to replace 64  of these lines with 64 new different strings.

I have this script - and it does change the 2nd field - however, it changes the 1st matched line correctly - but leaves the remaining lines unchanged - it keeps doing this until it reads the end of the file. So it looks like a loop issue.

Any ideas?  Here is the script:

```
while read line
    do sed  -e "0,/wwid/ s/wwid .*$/wwid "${line}"/" oldluns
done < newluns
```

Comment: Does `oldluns` consist entirely of lines like the one shown?

Comment: I understand what your saying - I removed the 0,/wwid part

Comment: sorry - hit return - I removed the 0,wwid part - but that changes ALL the 64 lines with the 1st new string - then changes ALL the same 64 lines and changes them to the next new string and so on until it reads the entire input file...

Comment: Yes I realized that after I commented - sorry

Comment: like this : - the same string shows 64 times   multipath {
                wwid 4624a9370dcb2348b03884049000110b2
                
        }
        multipath {
                wwid 4624a9370dcb2348b03884049000110b2

Comment: Yes your sed loop approach is only going to be feasible if the replacement string is sufficiently different that it doesn't match the pattern on subsequent iterations

Comment: It's preferable to edit the question rather than amending it in the comments section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sed loop approach is only going to work if the replacement text doesn't match the original pattern (otherwise `0,/wwid/` is going to match the instance you already replaced). For example, you could do

```
while read line
    do sed -i -e "0,/wwid/ s/wwid .*$/WWID "${line}"/" oldluns
done < newluns
```

and then post-process the result with another sed to change `WWID` back to `wwid`. Obviously you should choose a string that's not found elsewhere in the file.

(**NB** unfortunately this can't be tested without the `-i`, for the same reason - make sure you have suitable backups of the `oldluns` file.)

A better way might be to use `awk` e.g.

```
awk -vnewluns="newluns" '$1 == "wwid" {getline $2 < newluns} 1' oldluns
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response - both  your suggestions work - the awk reply is a bit cleaner - and explanation is good as well.